# drupalchat with nodejs

Tags: nodejs

I need to run drupalchat with nodejs locally but I get error loading the socket.io.js client library (404 not found)

nodejs server is running

the file exist in that path :

> sites/all/modules/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js

the request:

> http://localhost/drupal:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js

noddejs config:`settings = {
  scheme: 'http',
  port: 8282,
  host: 'localhost',
  resource: '/socket.io',
  serviceKey: '',
  backend: {
    port: 82,
    host: 'localhost',
    scheme: 'http',
    basePath: 'localhost/drupal',
    messagePath: '/nodejs/message'
  },
  debug: false,
  sslKeyPath: '',
  sslCertPath: '',
  sslCAPath: '',
  baseAuthPath: '/nodejs/',
  publishUrl: 'publish',
  kickUserUrl: 'user/kick/:uid',
  logoutUserUrl: 'user/logout/:authtoken',
  addUserToChannelUrl: 'user/channel/add/:channel/:uid',
  removeUserFromChannelUrl: 'user/channel/remove/:channel/:uid',
  addChannelUrl: 'channel/add/:channel',
  removeChannelUrl: 'channel/remove/:channel',
  setUserPresenceListUrl: 'user/presence-list/:uid/:uidList',
  addAuthTokenToChannelUrl: 'authtoken/channel/add/:channel/:uid',
  removeAuthTokenFromChannelUrl: 'authtoken/channel/remove/:channel/:uid',
  toggleDebugUrl: 'debug/toggle',
  contentTokenUrl: 'content/token',
  publishMessageToContentChannelUrl: 'content/token/message',
  extensions: [],
  clientsCanWriteToChannels: false,
  clientsCanWriteToClients: false,
  transports: ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling'],
  jsMinification: true,
  jsEtag: true,
  logLevel: 1
};`

what is wrong/missing config/permissions to run them together?

thanks in advance

Comment: The URL's wrong (the port should be after the domain, e.g. http://localhost:8080/...), and your node server is listening on 8282

Comment: changing port didn't matter

Comment: can you test with another module that uses nodejs to see if it's your nodejs or not. From talking to the people at iflychat they said that the nodejs feature is not production ready. It mentions on the drupal page "(currently under development)". Idk why they would have it there if it's not working.

Comment: I tried using it with my nodejs, but when I switch the option to use nodejs, the chat goes offline. When I try typing on it, I get this error on my terminal "publishMessageToChannel: The channel "drupalchat_c-0" doesn't exist.
" Seems to me that the nodejs feature is not ready for use at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created simple module to Integrate nodejs and build chat server for drupal users  [d7 nodejs chat](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mhmd/2508219)